# add dash to sub menu within array in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have created a tree level menu but I wanted to separate all sub menus by simply adding -- to every sub menu like

```
main menu
-- 1st level
---- 2nd level
------ 3rd level
and so on
```

while doing it in LI it is so easy I can simply put  tag before running my function but in select option I am unable to achive my target can anyone here would be able to help me out with this please

```
function fetch_menu($data) {
        foreach($data as $menu) {
            echo "<option value='".$menu->cid."'>".$menu->cname."</option>";

            if(!empty($menu->sub)) {
                fetch_sub_menu($menu->sub);
            }
        }
    }

    function fetch_sub_menu($sub_menu, $dash = '--'){
        foreach($sub_menu as $menu){
            echo "<option value='".$menu->cid."'>".$dash.$menu->cname."</option>";

            if(!empty($menu->sub)) {
                fetch_sub_menu($menu->sub, '--');
            }       

        }
    }
```

The problem is that while applying the above shown code that dash are not increasing for every 2nd or 3rd level menu 
 Here is how my data is organized in array form

```
array (
    [cid] => 1,
    [cname] => 'Main Menu',
    [pcid] => 0,
    [sub] => array(
        [cid] => 2,
        [cname] => '1st Level',
        [pcid] => 1,
        [sub] => array(
            [cid] => 3,
            [cname] => '2nd Level',
            [pcid] => 2,
            [sub] => array(

            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the new dashes to your `$dash` variable before recursivly calling the function again. That should work

```
function fetch_sub_menu($sub_menu, $dash = '--'){
    foreach($sub_menu as $menu){
        echo "<option value='".$menu->cid."'>".$dash.$menu->cname."</option>";

        if(!empty($menu->sub)) {
            fetch_sub_menu($menu->sub, $dash.'--'); // <-- adding two dashes to $dash
        }       

    }
}
```

Comment: such a simple thing how did I missed this thank you soo much fo the help

Comment: I clicked on accepted sorry I thought the answer was accepted done now